# Apache Spark: Difference between parallelize and broadcast

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In Spark (python):

If `sc` is a Spark context (`pyspark.SparkContext`), what is the difference between:

`r = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])`

and

`r = sc.broadcast([1,2,3,4,5])`
?

Comment: This first one creates an [rdd](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds), the other a [broadcast variable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An RDD in Spark is just a collection split into partitions (at least one).
Each partition lives on an executor which process it.
With sc.parallelize(), your collection is split in partitions assigned to executors, so for example you could have [1,2] on an executor, [3] on another, [4,5] on another one. In this way executors process the partitions in parallel. 
With broadcast as GwydionFR said, the passed parameter is copied to each executor.

Answer (score 11):

`sc.parallelize(...)` spread the data amongst all executors

`sc.broadcast(...)` copy the data in the jvm of each executor